# Failed since returned path does not exist

Tags: .net, azureservicebus, nservicebus

Failed since returned path (D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data) does not exist.

Unable to determine the diagnostics output directory. Check the attached exception for further information, or configure a custom diagnostics directory using `'EndpointConfiguration.SetDiagnosticsPath()'`.

```
System.Exception: Detected running in a website and attempted to use
HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Data/") to derive the logging path.
Failed since path returned (D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\) does not
exist. Ensure this directory is created and restart the endpoint.   
at NServiceBus.Host.DeriveAppDataPath(Assembly systemWebAssembly)   
at NServiceBus.Host.GetOutputDirectory()    at
NServiceBus.HostStartupDiagnostics.BuildDefaultDiagnosticsWriter(ReadOnlySettings
settings)
```

Comment: Are you on Windows and what webserver are you using? IIS or anything else?

Comment: Hosting environment is Azure PaaS.

Answer (score 0):

This exception typically occurs when the `App_Data` folder does not exist. Try creating this folder manually inside your project. If this doesn't help or you're using a different base directory, you can configure a different path using the `endpointConfiguration.SetDiagnosticsPath`. This is also described in the official documentation here: https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/startup-diagnostics

If that doesn't resolve the issue, you need to provide some more details about your configuration and hosting environment, pasting an exception without further context is not very helpful.

Comment: Azure PaaS WebApp is hosting environment so that we can not create manually, what is the best way to configure Azure WebApp path to endpointConfiguration.SetDiagnosticsPath.

Comment: @JagadeeshB You can create the folder manually by going to the App Service Editor (under Development tools) in WebApp (in the Azure Portal) and then creating the App_Data folder inside the wwwroot folder.

Comment: You can also create a file in the App_Data folder in your project, that should deploy the App_Data folder to the WebApp as well. Or you right-click the App_Data folder in Visual Studio and explicitly publish that folder too.